# Openfire access to database with webservice

Tags: web-services, openfire

I want to develop a IM client with openfire. And there is an existed system with database, we need openfire to access to the existed database to find the users.
I want to operate the database with webservice.
How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to use an external database, use this tutorial, it works well [openfire integration](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/db-integration-guide.html)
There is no way to use webservices to do this

Comment: Thanks for you reply. You mean that there is only one way to sync the username and password with editing openfire.xml. There is no way to sent  a post request to service to sync the information, is it right?

Comment: You can edit settings in web panel in server properties. You can use the restAPI plugin to get some information but external database integration is necessary